# Populate Fact Table with Talend

Tags: mysql, business-intelligence, talend, dimensional-modeling, fact-table

I need to populate my MySQL tables. I have the following dimensional schema.

[image]

All my foreign keys are in the fact table.

I have a CSV file for each thema.
Let's say excel1.csv corresponds to thema1 and excel2.csv corresponds to thema2.

All theme, regions,department, mois table are set. So I filled them manually:

**For example Theme table:**

idTheme | Theme

1          | Theme1

2          | Theme2

**Region table:**

idRegion | Region

1          | IDF

2          | Nord

3          | Bretagne

**Departement table:**

idDepartement | idRegion | Departement

1                   |     1      | Essonne

2                   |     1      | Paris

3                   |     1      | Seine Et Marne

4                   |     2      | Pas de Calais

5                   |     2      | Picardie

6                   |     3      | Calvados

7                   |     3      | Finistère

**Annee table:**

idAnnee | Annee

1          | 2013

2          | 2014

3          | 2015

**Mois table:**

idMois  | idAnnee  | Mois

1        | 3           | Janvier

2        | 3           | Février

3        | 3           | Mars
...

Now let's take excel1.csv file corresponding to thema1 (so idtheme=1):

NOM/Region/Departement/Mois/Poids

Adrien/IDF/Paris/Février/85

Louis/IDF/Paris/Janvier/84

Charles/Bretagne/Finistère/Janvier/90
...

I know how to fill my Client table thanks to tMap tranformation in Talend:
I get:

idClient/NOM/Poids

1/Adrien/85

2/Louis/84

3/Charles/90

**And I want my fact table to be like :**

idTheme/idDepartement/idClient/idMois

1/2/1/2

1/2/2/1

1/7/3/1

so that it will contains the foreign keys of other dimension tables.

I know how to fill dimension tables (manually most of the time and with tMap for Client table) but I'd like to fill my fact table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this model in your database, and your tables are created with all primary and foreign keys but still empty, then ceate a job that populate data that start from outside to inside in this order: Region, departement, Annee, Mois, theme, client, satisfaction.

Foreign keys are populated like any other field but the [constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Defining_foreign_keys) which is already defined with table creation, should be garenteed by joining data.

For the fact table you will need to read previously populated dimensions and [join](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Doing+an+inner+join+using+a+tMap+component) all foreign keys of all dimensions.

Comment: Yes I understand I must fill the dimension tables but my problem is how ?
For example when I fill Region it's ok but then I need to fill department and I don't know how to set idRegion in it because it is a foreign key.

Comment: @AdriL. For more clarity, All fields of a table holds the data that you see when you make a select, but we need sometimes to add some conditions on fields called constraints, foreign key is a data field and its data should exists in the primary key filed of the parent table.

Comment: Yes I know for the creation I wrote 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Region(
idRegion INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Region VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Department(
idDepartment INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
idRegion INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Dep_region FOREIGN KEY (idRegion) REFERENCES Region(idRegion),
Department VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL);

But the problem is when i have my csv file with nom/region/dpartment/mois/poids/... i need to put region in Region table (already done) but also department and idRegion in Department table :(